# comparison of datetime value and system date time fails

Tags: php, datetimepicker

i have the expiry date saved for each post using date time picker, now i need to check it against the current date and time each time  aperson visits the page and display msg according to whether its expired ornot...but the comparison fails

i tried with `date()`,`date create from format` and `DateTime::createFromFormat`...but it fails the check `if (is_a($expirydate, 'DateTime'))`.

```
$todaydate=new DateTime();
$todaydate->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$expirydate=strtotime(get_field('expirydate',$post->ID));
$expirydate=date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $expirydate);
if (is_a($todaydate, 'DateTime')) {
        echo "today date is datetime";
        if (is_a($expirydate, 'DateTime')) {    
            echo "expiry date check passed";

}}
if ($expirydate >= $todaydate) 
    {
    echo "not expired";
    }
```

it echos the msg today date is datetime but thats all...doesnt display msg "expiry date check passed" or "not expired"...its shud diplay all of the 3 messages.

Comment: I suggest you to first convert them into timestamp then you can compare them as int like ```php     if(strtotime($firstTime) >= strtotime($secondTime)){ //Do something }    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with strtotime is Old School. Better use DateTime. DateTime objects can also be compared directly.

```
$expirydate=date_create(get_field('expirydate',$post->ID));
//$expirydate=date_create('today 11:19');  //for a test

$todaydate=new DateTime('Now'); //with current Time
//$todaydate=new DateTime('Today'); //with Time 00:00

if($todaydate > $expirydate) {
  echo 'expired';
}
```